# Custom FaultContract returned as ExceptionDetail

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to throw a custom **FaultContract** from a WCF service to a ASP.NET application, using Tcp Binding.

I have defined the fault contract-

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomFault
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeData { get; set; }

    public CustomFault(string someData)
    {
        SomeData = someData;
    }
}
```

I have specified the fault contract on the service operation:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(CustomFault))]
void AddProductToBasket(Guid basketId, int productId, decimal quantity, int uomId);
```

I am throwing it like:

```
throw new FaultException<CustomFault>(new CustomFault("LowStock"));
```

And trying to catch it like this:

```
try
{
    // Do service operation.
}
catch (FaultException<CustomFault> fault)
{
    // Successfully caught typed FaultException<CustomFault>
    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Failed, caught FaultException<ExceptionDetail>
    throw;
}
```

But the catch always catches something of type `FaultException<ExceptionDetail>`, I believe this happens when you specify **<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />**, which I have done for other exceptions, but having specified the FaultContract for the operation it should use the custom FaultContract instead...

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Have you confirmed the serviceDebug hunch by removing the serviceDebug line from your config?

Comment: Yes (Just throws standard "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.") - It looks like it just can't serialize or resolve the custom fault contract...

Comment: If you are getting "The server was unable to process the request..." then I think the exception you are catching isn't the fault that you are expecting. Something completely different is broken. Put a high level catch block around all your AddProductToBasket() on the service side (or implement IErrorHandler) and see what you can catch there.